# How to dock Device File Explorer to the side in Android Studio 3.1.3?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

I accidently undocked the Device File Explorer from the side bar, now it keeps popping up. I want it to be docked so that the UI may be clean. I can't find any option to dock it back again.

I even tried Shift + F12 which restores view to the Android Studio default view but it didn't help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `settings` icon on your `device explorer window` and then `un-select -> floating mode`.

[image]